# How to recover from a major mistake that breaks yum

Tags: python, yum, reinstall

I was attempting to update my CentOS 7 system tonight and kept getting an error from python-urllib3. I tracked down the error to a directory that should not have been present.

So, I went to remove the offending directory and inadvertently deleted the parent instead. In this case, the parent was /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Anyone who has worked with yum for long enough knows that would break yum, so... What to do? The solution I came up with is below, and worked to fix my system.

Depending on what modifications were made to your system, you may have to re-do some of those (customized configurations in /etc are overwritten by yum reinstall) but this should work for 99% of cases.

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux and thanks for an *excellent* first question *and* an *excellent* first answer!  **:-)** **+1 to both!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since rpm does not require python (thank god), we use rpm to find out the full name of every package that either has python in the name, or requires the base python package.

```
# rpm -qa |grep -i python |sort
# rpm -q --whatrequires python |sort
```

Once you have the full list of packages, you need to find out where yum downloads them from.

```
# grep -i '\[base\]' /etc/yum.repos.d/*
```

This should give you /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

Then, you need to visit the mirrorlist page with your web browser

```
# egrep 'mirrorlist.*=(os|updates)' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

There should be 2 lines. You'll have to do a tiny bit of modification to them (in a notepad!) before you paste it to the browser:

```
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
```

Specifically, you need to change the release and arch, and delete the infra.

Mine ended up looking like this when I went to paste it.

```
http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=updates
http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os
```

Once that was done, I was able to wget all of the packages I needed by combining several of the commands above together into 4 one-liner scripts:

```
# while read line; do wget http://yum.tamu.edu/centos/7.5.1804/updates/x86_64/Packages/${line}.rpm; done < <(while read line; do rpm -ql ${line} |grep -iq /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo ${line}; fi; done < <(rpm -q --whatrequires python |sort))
# while read line; do wget http://yum.tamu.edu/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/${line}.rpm; done < <(while read line; do rpm -ql ${line} |grep -iq /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo ${line}; fi; done < <(rpm -q --whatrequires python |sort))
# while read line; do wget http://yum.tamu.edu/centos/7.5.1804/updates/x86_64/Packages/${line}.rpm; done < <(while read line; do rpm -ql ${line} |grep -iq /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo ${line}; fi; done < <(rpm -qa |grep -i python |sort))
# while read line; do wget http://yum.tamu.edu/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/${line}.rpm; done < <(while read line; do rpm -ql ${line} |grep -iq /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo ${line}; fi; done < <(rpm -qa |grep -i python |sort))
```

Note, if you copy and paste the package names from the rpm commands above into a text file on your distro, this could be reduced to 2 lines. For example, if you place the package names into /tmp/packagedownload.txt, you could do the following, instead of the above:

```
# while read line; do wget http://yum.tamu.edu/centos/7.5.1804/updates/x86_64/Packages/${line}.rpm; done </tmp/packagedownload.txt
# while read line; do wget http://yum.tamu.edu/centos/7.5.1804/os/x86_64/Packages/${line}.rpm; done </tmp/packagedownload.txt
```

Once the rpm files are downloaded with wget, you can simply issue the below command to fix the system, and get yum working:

```
# rpm -ivh --force *.rpm
```

Then you can fix any other packages that might still be broken (hopefully none are) by issuing the below:

```
# while read line; do xargs yum -y reinstall $line; done </tmp/packagedownload.txt
```

Comment: In case anyone is curious about the loops I use. This is a practice I picked up after a certain bash script syntax checking website indicated that it is slightly less convoluted than piping the output of a command to a while loop, so I just write it that way by default. As long as the data is the same, the loop can be written however you want to do it (`command |while read line`, `for i in \`command\``, etc all work just fine for this). It's just personal preference.